# Make Boto3 upload calls blocking (single threaded)

Tags: python, boto3

**Edit**: my original assumption was proved partly wrong.  I've added a lengthy answer here on which I invite others to stress-test and correct.

---

I am looking for a way to utilize the Boto3 S3 API in a single-threaded manner to mimic a threadsafe key-value store.  In a nutshell, I want to **use the calling thread rather than a new thread** to do the upload.

The default behavior of the [`.upload_fileobj()`](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/78c87247d0ced972ec68cbcb5e1b0ca722362b26/boto3/s3/inject.py#L485) method in Boto3 (or `.upload_file()`), as far as I can tell, is to kick the task off to a new thread and return `None` immediately.

From the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.upload_fileobj):

> This is a managed transfer which will perform a multipart upload in multiple threads if necessary.

(If my understanding of this is wrong in the first place, a correcton on that would be helpful as well.  This is in Boto3 1.9.134.)

```
>>> import io
>>> import boto3
>>> bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('my-bucket-name')
>>> buf = io.BytesIO(b"test")
>>> res = bucket.upload_fileobj(buf, 'testobj')
>>> res is None
True
```

Now, let's say that `buf` is not a short 4-byte string, but a huge text blob that's going to take a non-negligible amount of time to fully upload.

I also use this function to check if an object with a given key exists:

```
def key_exists_in_bucket(bucket_obj, key: str) -> bool:
    try:
        bucket_obj.Object(key).load()
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

My intention is to not re-write the object if it exists by name.

The race condition here is fairly obvious: kick off an upload asynchronously, then do a quick check with `key_exists_in_bucket()`, getting back `False` if the object is still being written, then go to write it again unnecessarily as a result of that.

**Is there a way to ensure that `bucket.upload_fileobj()` is called by the *current thread* rather than a new thread created within the scope of that method?**

I realize that this will slow things down.  I'm willing to sacrifice speed in this case.

Comment: I've used S3 client and resource level APIs to upload files in the past and they were all blocking iirc. Are you sure this is even a problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured that, since both the answers to this question and [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37603148/7954504) seem to be in direct conflict, it would be best to go straight to the source with [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

#### Summary

- `boto3` *does* use multiple threads (10) by default
- However, it is not asynchronous, in that it *waits on* (joins) these threads before returning, rather than using a "fire-and-forget" technique
- So, in this manner, the read/write threadsafety *is* in place if you're trying to talk to an s3 bucket from multiple clients.

---

#### Detail

One aspect that I'm striving to address here is that **multiple (subthreads) do *not* imply that the top-level method itself is non-blocking**: if the calling thread kicks off the upload to multiple subthreads, but then *waits* for those threads to finish and return, I would venture to say that is still a blocking call.  The flip side of this is if the method call is, in `asyncio` speak, a "fire and forget" call.  With `threading`, this effectively comes down to whether `x.join()` is ever called.

Here is the initial code, taken from Victor Val, to kick off the debugger:

```
import io
import pdb

import boto3

# From dd if=/dev/zero of=100mb.txt  bs=50M  count=1
buf = io.BytesIO(open('100mb.txt', 'rb').read())
bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('test-threads')
pdb.run("bucket.upload_fileobj(buf, '100mb')")
```

This stack frame is from Boto 1.9.134.

Now jumping into `pdb`:

`.upload_fileobj()` first calls a nested method -- not much to see yet.

```
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /home/ubuntu/envs/py372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py(542)bucket_upload_fileobj()
-> def bucket_upload_fileobj(self, Fileobj, Key, ExtraArgs=None,
(Pdb) s

(Pdb) l
574     
575         :type Config: boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig
576         :param Config: The transfer configuration to be used when performing the
577             upload.
578         """
579  ->     return self.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
580             Fileobj=Fileobj, Bucket=self.name, Key=Key, ExtraArgs=ExtraArgs,
581             Callback=Callback, Config=Config)
582     
583     
584
```

So the top-level method does return *something*, but its unclear yet how that something eventually becomes `None`.

So we step into that.

Now, `.upload_fileobj()` does have a `config` parameter, which is None by default:

```
(Pdb) l 531
526     
527         subscribers = None
528         if Callback is not None:
529             subscribers = [ProgressCallbackInvoker(Callback)]
530     
531         config = Config
532         if config is None:
533             config = TransferConfig()
534     
535         with create_transfer_manager(self, config) as manager:
536             future = manager.upload(
```

This means that `config` becomes the default [`TransferConfig()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig):

- `use_threads` -- If True, threads will be used when performing S3 transfers. If False, no threads will be used in performing transfers: all logic will be ran in the main thread.
- `max_concurrency` -- The maximum number of threads that will be making requests to perform a transfer. If use_threads is set to False, the value provided is ignored as the transfer will only ever use the main thread.

And wa-la, here they are:

```
(Pdb) unt 534
> /home/ubuntu/envs/py372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py(535)upload_fileobj()
-> with create_transfer_manager(self, config) as manager:
(Pdb) config
<boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig object at 0x7f1790dc0cc0>
(Pdb) config.use_threads
True
(Pdb) config.max_concurrency
10
```

Now we descend down a level in the call stack to use a `TransferManager` (context manager).  At this point, `max_concurrency` has been used as an argument to similarly-named `max_request_concurrency`:

```
# https://github.com/boto/s3transfer/blob/2aead638c8385d8ae0b1756b2de17e8fad45fffa/s3transfer/manager.py#L223

    # The executor responsible for making S3 API transfer requests
    self._request_executor = BoundedExecutor(
        max_size=self._config.max_request_queue_size,
        max_num_threads=self._config.max_request_concurrency,
        tag_semaphores={
            IN_MEMORY_UPLOAD_TAG: TaskSemaphore(
                self._config.max_in_memory_upload_chunks),
            IN_MEMORY_DOWNLOAD_TAG: SlidingWindowSemaphore(
                self._config.max_in_memory_download_chunks)
        },
        executor_cls=executor_cls
    )
```

In this boto3 version, at least, that class comes from the separate library [`s3transfer`](https://github.com/boto/s3transfer/blob/develop/s3transfer/manager.py).

```
(Pdb) n
> /home/ubuntu/envs/py372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py(536)upload_fileobj()
-> future = manager.upload(
(Pdb) manager
<s3transfer.manager.TransferManager object at 0x7f178db437f0>
(Pdb) manager._config
<boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig object at 0x7f1790dc0cc0>
(Pdb) manager._config.use_threads
True
(Pdb) manager._config.max_concurrency
10
```

Next, let's step into `manager.upload()`.  Here's the full body of that method:

```
(Pdb) l 290, 303
290  ->         if extra_args is None:
291                 extra_args = {}
292             if subscribers is None:
293                 subscribers = []
294             self._validate_all_known_args(extra_args, self.ALLOWED_UPLOAD_ARGS)
295             call_args = CallArgs(
296                 fileobj=fileobj, bucket=bucket, key=key, extra_args=extra_args,
297                 subscribers=subscribers
298             )
299             extra_main_kwargs = {}
300             if self._bandwidth_limiter:
301                 extra_main_kwargs['bandwidth_limiter'] = self._bandwidth_limiter
302             return self._submit_transfer(
303                 call_args, UploadSubmissionTask, extra_main_kwargs)

(Pdb) unt 301
> /home/ubuntu/envs/py372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3transfer/manager.py(302)upload()
-> return self._submit_transfer(
(Pdb) extra_main_kwargs
{}

(Pdb) UploadSubmissionTask
<class 's3transfer.upload.UploadSubmissionTask'>
(Pdb) call_args
<s3transfer.utils.CallArgs object at 0x7f178db5a5f8>

(Pdb) l 300, 5
300             if self._bandwidth_limiter:
301                 extra_main_kwargs['bandwidth_limiter'] = self._bandwidth_limiter
302  ->         return self._submit_transfer(
303                 call_args, UploadSubmissionTask, extra_main_kwargs)
304     
305         def download(self, bucket, key, fileobj, extra_args=None,
```

Ah, lovely--so we'll need to get down at least one level further to see the actual underlying upload.

```
(Pdb) s
> /home/ubuntu/envs/py372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3transfer/manager.py(303)upload()
-> call_args, UploadSubmissionTask, extra_main_kwargs)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /home/ubuntu/envs/py372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3transfer/manager.py(438)_submit_transfer()
-> def _submit_transfer(self, call_args, submission_task_cls,
(Pdb) s
> /home/ubuntu/envs/py372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3transfer/manager.py(440)_submit_transfer()
-> if not extra_main_kwargs:

(Pdb) l 440, 10
440  ->         if not extra_main_kwargs:
441                 extra_main_kwargs = {}
442     
443             # Create a TransferFuture to return back to the user
444             transfer_future, components = self._get_future_with_components(
445                 call_args)
446     
447             # Add any provided done callbacks to the created transfer future
448             # to be invoked on the transfer future being complete.
449             for callback in get_callbacks(transfer_future, 'done'):
450                 components['coordinator'].add_done_callback(callback)
```

Okay, so now we have a `TransferFuture`, defined in [`s3transfer/futures.py`](https://github.com/boto/s3transfer/blob/develop/s3transfer/futures.py)  No definitive proof that threads have been kicked off yet, but it sure sounds like it when [futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) become involved.

```
(Pdb) l
444             transfer_future, components = self._get_future_with_components(
445                 call_args)
446     
447             # Add any provided done callbacks to the created transfer future
448             # to be invoked on the transfer future being complete.
449  ->         for callback in get_callbacks(transfer_future, 'done'):
450                 components['coordinator'].add_done_callback(callback)
451     
452             # Get the main kwargs needed to instantiate the submission task
453             main_kwargs = self._get_submission_task_main_kwargs(
454                 transfer_future, extra_main_kwargs)
(Pdb) transfer_future
<s3transfer.futures.TransferFuture object at 0x7f178db5a780>
```

The final line below, from the `TransferCoordinator` class, seems important at first glance:

```
class TransferCoordinator(object):
    """A helper class for managing TransferFuture"""
    def __init__(self, transfer_id=None):
        self.transfer_id = transfer_id
        self._status = 'not-started'
        self._result = None
        self._exception = None
        self._associated_futures = set()
        self._failure_cleanups = []
        self._done_callbacks = []
        self._done_event = threading.Event()  # < ------ !!!!!!
```

You typically see `threading.Event` [being used for one thread to signal](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#producer-consumer-using-queue) an event status while other threads can be waiting for that event to happen.

`TransferCoordinator` is what is [used by `TransferFuture.result()`](https://github.com/boto/s3transfer/blob/2aead638c8385d8ae0b1756b2de17e8fad45fffa/s3transfer/futures.py#L106).

Alright, circling back from the above, we're now at [`s3transfer.futures.BoundedExecutor`](https://github.com/boto/s3transfer/blob/2aead638c8385d8ae0b1756b2de17e8fad45fffa/s3transfer/futures.py#L401) and its `max_num_threads` attribute:

```
class BoundedExecutor(object):
    EXECUTOR_CLS = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor
    # ...
    def __init__(self, max_size, max_num_threads, tag_semaphores=None,
                 executor_cls=None):
    self._max_num_threads = max_num_threads
    if executor_cls is None:
        executor_cls = self.EXECUTOR_CLS
    self._executor = executor_cls(max_workers=self._max_num_threads)
```

This is basically [equivalent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) to:

```
from concurrent import futures

_executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
```

But there is still one question remaining: is this a "fire-and-forget," or does the call actually *wait on* the threads to finish and return?

It seems to be the latter.  `.result()` calls `self._done_event.wait(MAXINT)`.

```
# https://github.com/boto/s3transfer/blob/2aead638c8385d8ae0b1756b2de17e8fad45fffa/s3transfer/futures.py#L249

def result(self):
    self._done_event.wait(MAXINT)

    # Once done waiting, raise an exception if present or return the
    # final result.
    if self._exception:
        raise self._exception
    return self._result
```

Finally, to re-run Victor Val's test, this seems to confirm the above:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> import time
>>> import io
>>> 
>>> buf = io.BytesIO(open('100mb.txt', 'rb').read())
>>> 
>>> bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('test-threads')
>>> start = time.time()
>>> print("starting to upload...")
starting to upload...
>>> bucket.upload_fileobj(buf, '100mb')
>>> print("finished uploading")
finished uploading
>>> end = time.time()
>>> print("time: {}".format(end-start))
time: 2.6030001640319824
```

(This execution time is probably shorter with this example run on a network-optimized instance.  But 2.5 seconds is still a noticeably big chunk of time, and not at all indicative of the threads being kicked off and not waited for.)

---

Lastly, here's an example of a `Callback` for `.upload_fileobj()`.  It follows along with [an example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html#the-callback-parameter) from the docs.

First, a little helper to get a buffer's size efficiently:

```
def get_bufsize(buf, chunk=1024) -> int:
    start = buf.tell()
    try:
        size = 0 
        while True: 
            out = buf.read(chunk) 
            if out: 
                size += chunk 
            else: 
                break
        return size
    finally:
        buf.seek(start)
```

The class itself:

```
import os
import sys
import threading
import time

class ProgressPercentage(object):
    def __init__(self, filename, buf):
        self._filename = filename
        self._size = float(get_bufsize(buf))
        self._seen_so_far = 0
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        self.start = None

    def __call__(self, bytes_amount):
        with self._lock:
            if not self.start:
                self.start = time.monotonic()
            self._seen_so_far += bytes_amount
            percentage = (self._seen_so_far / self._size) * 100
            sys.stdout.write(
                "\r%s  %s of %s  (%.2f%% done, %.2fs elapsed\n" % (
                    self._filename, self._seen_so_far, self._size,
                    percentage, time.monotonic() - self.start))
            # Use sys.stdout.flush() to update on one line
            # sys.stdout.flush()
```

Example:

```
In [19]: import io 
    ...:  
    ...: from boto3.session import Session 
    ...:  
    ...: s3 = Session().resource("s3") 
    ...: bucket = s3.Bucket("test-threads") 
    ...: buf = io.BytesIO(open('100mb.txt', 'rb').read()) 
    ...:  
    ...: bucket.upload_fileobj(buf, 'mykey', Callback=ProgressPercentage("mykey", buf))                                                                                                                                                                      
mykey  262144 of 104857600.0  (0.25% done, 0.00s elapsed
mykey  524288 of 104857600.0  (0.50% done, 0.00s elapsed
mykey  786432 of 104857600.0  (0.75% done, 0.01s elapsed
mykey  1048576 of 104857600.0  (1.00% done, 0.01s elapsed
mykey  1310720 of 104857600.0  (1.25% done, 0.01s elapsed
mykey  1572864 of 104857600.0  (1.50% done, 0.02s elapsed
```

Comment: Great work Brad! I was having a look at [callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827963/track-download-progress-of-s3-file-using-boto3-and-callbacks). Do you think this might be a valid way to check if during a call to upload a key, the same key is already being uploaded?

Comment: Interesting, will play around with that.  Looks like it could be used for that.

Comment: Wow! I got to the point where I figured out that the use_threads parameters did indeed decide use (or not use) multi-threading. Also, irrespective of the fact that multiple or a single thread is used, the call is blocking, as the main thread waits for all threads to join.

Comment: Added a callback example here for upload_fileobj @VictorVal.  But I think it still begs the question - can an individual client achieve a _server-side lock_.  Of that I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7):

The [upload_fileobj](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.upload_fileobj) takes in a Config parameter. This is a [boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig) object, which in turn has a parameter called `use_threads` (default true) - If True, threads will be used when performing S3 transfers. If False, no threads will be used in performing transfers: all logic will be ran in the main thread.

Hopefully this should work for you.

Comment: Wow I've been using this API for like 9 months and I didn't even know its possible to use multiple threads. Do you know under which conditions it will do that?

Comment: It will do it under all conditions unless set to false [see here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3.html#uploads)

Comment: @jmkmay It will always use multiple threads; If you don't want multi-threaded behaviour you need to explicitly create a `TransferConfig` object with `use_threads` set to `False` and pass this to the `upload_fileobj` function

Comment: @Verma Are you sure? Documentation says "This is a managed transfer which will perform a multipart upload in multiple threads if necessary." I know with other S3 operations it will only perform multi-part of the PUT exceeds a certain size threshold.

Comment: @BradSolomon The documentation and whatever code I have seen seems to indicate that single or multi-threaded execution can be controlled. What tests I have done seem to indicate the execution is always on the main thread. Trying to dig deeper into the code to see if I can get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 6):

**Testing if the method is blocking or not**:
I empirically tested this behaviour myself. First I generated a 100MB file with:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=100mb.txt  bs=100M  count=1
```

Then I tried to upload the file the same way you did and measure the time it took:

```
import boto3
import time
import io
file = open('100mb.txt', 'rb')
buf = io.BytesIO(file.read())
bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('testbucket')
start = time.time()
print("starting to upload...")
bucket.upload_fileobj(buf, '100mb')
print("finished uploading")
end = time.time()
print("time: {}".format(end-start))
```

It took over 8 seconds for the upload_fileobj() method to finish and the next python line to be read (50 seconds for a 1gb file), so **I assume that this method is blocking**.

**Testing with threading**:

When using multiple threads I can verify that the method supports multiple transfers at the same time **even with the option use_threads=False**. I started uploading a 200mb file and then a 100mb and the 100mb file finished first. This confirms that the concurrency in *TransferConfig* is related to multipart transfers.

Code:

```
import boto3
import time
import io
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig
import threading

config = TransferConfig(use_threads=False)

bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('testbucket')
def upload(filename):
     file = open(filename, 'rb')
     buf = io.BytesIO(file.read())
     start = time.time()
     print("starting to upload file {}".format(filename))
     bucket.upload_fileobj(buf,filename,Config=config)
     end = time.time()
     print("finished uploading file {}. time: {}".format(filename,end-start))
x1 = threading.Thread(target=upload, args=('200mb.txt',))
x2 = threading.Thread(target=upload, args=('100mb.txt',))
x1.start()
time.sleep(2)
x2.start()
```

Output:

> starting to upload file 200mb.txt
>   starting to upload file 100mb.txt
>   finished uploading file 100mb.txt. time: 46.35254502296448
>   finished uploading file 200mb.txt. time: 61.70564889907837

**Testing with Sessions**:
This is what you need if you want the upload method to be finished in the order it is called.

Code:

```
import boto3
import time
import io
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig
import threading

config = TransferConfig(use_threads=False)

session = boto3.session.Session()
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('testbucket')
def upload(filename):
     file = open(filename, 'rb')
     buf = io.BytesIO(file.read())
     start = time.time()
     print("starting to upload file {}".format(filename))
     bucket.upload_fileobj(buf,filename)
     end = time.time()
     print("finished uploading file {}. time: {}".format(filename,end-start))
x1 = threading.Thread(target=upload, args=('200mb.txt',))
x2 = threading.Thread(target=upload, args=('100mb.txt',))
x1.start()
time.sleep(2)
x2.start()
```

Output:

> starting to upload file 200mb.txt
>   starting to upload file 100mb.txt
>   finished uploading file 200mb.txt. time: 46.62478971481323
>   finished uploading file 100mb.txt. time: 50.515950202941895

Some resources I found:
 - [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603148/is-boto3-bucket-upload-file-blocking-or-non-blocking) is a question asked here in SO about the method being blocking or non-blocking. It is not conclusive but there might be relevant info in there.
 - There is an open [issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/648) at GitHub to allow assynchronous transfers in boto3.
 - There is also tools like [aioboto](https://github.com/terrycain/aioboto3) and [aiobotocore](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore) specifically made to allow async download and upload from/to s3 and other aws services.

**About my previous answer**:
You can read [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3.html) about File Transfer Configurations in boto3. In particular:

> Transfer operations use threads to implement concurrency. Thread use
>   can be disabled by setting the use_threads attribute to False.

Initially I thought that this was related to mutliple transfers being executed concurrently. However reading the [source code](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/s3/transfer.html) the comment in the parameter *max_concurrency* when using *TransferConfig* explains that the concurrency does not refers to multiple transfers but to the 
*"number of threads that will be making requests to perform a transfer"*. So it's something used to speed up the transfer. The *use_threads* attribute is used only to allow concurrency in multipart transfers.

Comment: I tested it and the upload is blocking the execution for me. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I was playing around with threading and sessions. Apparently when I create a session object I am able to execute the upload one each time. Strangely the time to complete the 100mb upload is just a few seconds after the 200mb one, so there might be the chance that the 100mb upload started before the 200mb finished, but it always waits for the 200mb to finish before finishing itself. I've tried using `s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=botocore.client.Config(max_pool_connections=1))` and the behaviour didn't change

Comment: Note: you should **not** share the same `s3.Bucket` among multiple threads. See the [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html?highlight=thread#multithreading-multiprocessing). We've been bit before by this, and now scrupulously make a new `Session` for each working thread.